# How to make a customer keyboard insert attributed text (e.g., website link) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I'm making a 3rd-party keyboard for the iPhone, and can get the keyboard to insert a specific string via:

```
(textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText("\(string)")
```

Unfortunately the insertText function only takes a string argument - is there a way to make it take an NSAttributedString, or a workaround that allows me to put an NSAttributedString into the text field the user is typing into?

I basically want part of "string" to be the URL of my app on the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You can only insert String / NSString objects from a keyboard extension.

One common workaround is to put it in

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
```

but this relies on the user then long-pressing and pasting it into the text field themselves, which is a horrible UX and seems like overkill for your use-case. Maybe it would be sufficient to include the 'https://' in the URL and then the app the user is typing in should hopefully detect that it's a link and display it as such. That's not guaranteed though.